# How do I pass multiple objects from a ViewModel to a jQuery function?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and would like to know how to pass values from a `ViewModel` into a `jQuery` function where I have a list of data to pass.

Usually, I would create a `hidden` field in the `MVC` `View` code, and then retrieve this value in the `jQuery` code. However, in this situation, there is not just one value from the `ViewModel`, but a `List` of objects, where each object has many values.

My `ViewModel` has a `List<MapMarker>`, where each `MapMarker` has the following attributes:

- latitude
- longitude
- title
- draggable

This is the `jQuery` function that I need to call for each `MapMarker` object:

```
function LoadMapMarker(latitude, longitude, title, draggable)
```

How can I call the `LoadMapMarker` function, with data from each of the `MapMarker` objects in the `ViewModel` list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you pass complete view model to function?

Comment: You can add class to your main "div" , and do something like :
$(".YourClass").each(function (....))

Comment: Why not use AJAX and JSON to do this?

Comment: @Daniel, using AJAX is a good option to retrieve data from services or action result that works like a service (eg: returns JSON instead of View). If there is a view for the action result, this is possible in razor and no need for AJAX request to retrieve the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize your list and storage it in a hidden field. Then call LoadMapMarker by means of Javascript on client side.

**Server:**

```
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization; 
    var MapMarkers = new List<MapMarker>();
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(MapMarkers);
    return View(new MyViewModel({JsonList = json }));
```

**View:**

```
<input type="hidden" id= "MyHiddenFieldForMapMarker" value="@Model.JsonList" >
```

**Client:**

```
var MapMarkers = $("#MyHiddenFieldForMapMarker").val();
for (var MapMarker in MapMarkers) {
   LoadMapMarker(MapMarker["latitude"],
                 MapMarker["longitude"],
                 MapMarker["title"],
                 MapMarker["draggable"]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize to JSON and then store in a hidden field, or as a Javascript object like :

`myJsonData= [{"id":"15aea3fa","firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}];`

Alternatively, you can retrieve the data via an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

If your jQuery function is present in a view, use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.JSonData))` like this

```
//JavaScript or jQuery function
function javascriptFunction()
{
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.JSonData))
}
```

In the above code, JSonData is the name of the collection variable that contains data from model. In your case a List.

If your **jQuery function is in a separate JavaScript file**, then an AJAX request can be used to get the data from model

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    //Your logic to get data from model
    //Here data is the variable that holds the collection List<MapMarker>
    return Json(data);
}
```

**JavaScript Code for AJAX Request**

```
function myJavaScriptFunction()
{
     $.ajax({
        url: '/GetData',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("data retrieved successfully");
        },

        error: function () {
            alert("Error retrieving data");
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JSON and use the data you have on your page you can do this:

You can add class (or some other attribute, for me it is easier to use classes, but it is better "programming" to use another attribute)

```
@foreach ()... 
{
   <div class="main_Marker">
     <input ... class="lat"/>  //using the @Model render ofc...
     <input ... class="long"/>
   </div>
}
```

Then jQuery:

```
$("main_Marker").each(function(index, item)) {
   var lat = $(item).child(".lat");
   .
   .
   LoadMapMarker(lat, long....);
}
```